# How to read a text file into an arraylist in JAVA?

Tags: java

I need help on a part of my JAVA program HW. I don't understand how to read a file into an array list. please help thanks!

getBreadInfo - reads bread.txt into an array list (containing bread
name, $, and price) and then assigns to an array breadInfo[], then
return this array for SandwichApp to display bread menu.

getBread - is similar to getBreadInfo, except it only contains the
bread name, and return another array bread[] for SandwichApp to figure
out which bread the user selected because user type in a number
associate with the bread (index+1), rather than bread name.

getMapBreadPrice - is similar to the above two, except it returns a
hash map containing pair values for bread name (key) and price (value)
for SandwichApp to figure out what is the price for the bread user
selected.

and the bread.txt file reads

White Bread~1.50

Wheat Bread~1.80

French Bread~2.00

Organic Bread~2.30

Comment: post some source code please and maybe your exact/specific error

Comment: Have a read through [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I just don't know where to start. Been stuck on this for awhile reading my book can't find any examples on it. and thanks i'll go ahead and read that basic i/o.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest code:

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bread.txt"));
    List<String> breadsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> priceList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = null;
    while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
        String[] elems = line.split("~");
        breadsList.add(elems[0]);
        priceList.add(elems[1]);
    }
    String[] breads = breadsList.toArray(new String[]{});
    String[] prices= priceList.toArray(new String[]{});
```

Comment: @JustinPancakeRazon: If this was helpful, can you accept the answer by clicking arrow sign down the vote count in front of the answer?